# Evolution Contacts not Auto-populating

Tags: evolution, contacts, gmail

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and Evolution 2.28.3. I have Evolution configured to use my gmail contacts.

When composing a message, entering addresses does not automatically resolve in any way. In order to use an address from my contacts, I need to click on the **To:** button and select contacts from the list. The list itself is fine - all my contacts are present.

Is there any way to have Evolution automatically resolve email addresses as I type? I've looked through the preferences and found nothing helpful.

Comment: In the Evolution preferences pane, in "Contacts", do you have your Gmail account checked for auto-completion ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by checking **three** boxes:

a. Evolution-Mail -> Edit -> Preferences -> Contacts -> [x] Always show address of the autocompleted contact / [x] Gmail

b. Evolution-Contacts -> Gmail -> Properties -> [x] Autocomplete with this address book

Hope that helps.